# React Date Picker not showing in a bootstrap accordion

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-datepicker

I've integrated [react-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker) in a project I'm working on. the project is using react-bootstrap.

I'm trying to use react-date-picker inside an accordion. but it is not rendering correctly.

How can I fix this? has anyone experience same problem before?

```
<Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
  <Card>
    <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="0">
      Accordion Header
    </Accordion.Toggle>
    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
      <Card.Body>
        <DatePicker selected={startDate} showTimeSelect onChange={date => setStartDate(date)} />
      </Card.Body>
    </Accordion.Collapse>
  </Card>
</Accordion>
```

[image]

Comment: Please make code sandbox example, so we can help you?

Comment: Working on that at codesandbox will update the question asap